# Difference between CreateAttribute and setAttribute c#

Tags: c#, attributes, system.xml

I see that there are different ways to create an xml, add nodes and set attributes for them. But i would like to get the difference between these two:

```
XmlNode infoNode = xmlDocument.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "INFO", string.Empty);
XmlAttribute idAttribute = xmlDocument.CreateAttribute("Id");
idAttribute.Value = this._id.ToString();
infoNode.Attributes.Append(instanceIdAttribute);


XmlElement infoNode= setTCAreaXml.CreateElement("INFO");
infoNode.SetAttribute("Id", this._Id.ToString());
```

Which the best to use? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`CreateAttribute` will do just that. Create a new `Attribute` which you then `Append` to a `Node`.

[From the doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/08dy2b79(v=vs.110).aspx);

> Creates an XmlAttribute with the specified Name.

`SetAttribute` will set the value of an existing `Attribute`. If the `Attribute` doesn't exist, a new one will be created and its value set.

[From the doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.setattribute(v=vs.110).aspx);

> Sets the value of the specified XmlAttribute.